# Flutter if statement within widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Not sure why this if statement is not working:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          if (text.length > 0) {
             for (var val in text) Center(child: etc..)
            }
        ],
      ),
)
```

The code within the if statement (removed for now) works fine without the if statement, but as soon as I add it I get the error `The element type 'Map' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'`.

How should I compose this if statement within a widget? I realise it's within a `return` statement but not sure why the for loop is fine but not the if statement..

Comment: If statements inside widgets don't have curly brackets. Remove the ```{}``` for the if statement

Comment: @danypata Oh right....as simple as that eh? I was gonna say, it looked fine enough to me. I didn't see what the problem was.

Comment: @casraf So what if it's some kind of long multiple line statement within the if statement? Without curly brackets that would get a bit difficult.

Comment: text.length > 0 ? for (var val in text) Center(child: etc..)  : null should also work but again it might be tricky if the statement is long

Comment: @Can Taşpınar So what you do if the statement is longer? It's no problem in this case but for future reference.

Comment: @Hasen Well, you can create a function and pass things as parameters if necessary. Complex logic or long statements can be handled inside that function. At the end it will return true or false so a simple line like check(foo) ? Container() ; null would the job.

Comment: @Hasen Ok so the only way is to make a function, we're basically limited to one liners direct in the widget. Ok got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for loop` is fine inside collection because it is new *Dart* feature (starting from version 2.3). For example next snippet generates new list of squares:

```
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var squares = [for (var n in numbers) n * n];
  print(squares); // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

`if` inside collection also new for Dart 2.3 and allow filter elements out:

```
  bool includeZero = false;
  var all = [if (includeZero) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  print(all); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can even combine both construction:

```
  var includeSquares = true;
  var allWithSquares = [
    ...numbers,
    if (includeSquares) for (var n in numbers) n * n
  ];
  print(allWithSquares); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

The only thing you can't do is use curly braces as code blocks inside collections.
You still can use curly braces to define Map as element. In your case curly braces gives next result:

```
  var includeSquares = true;
  var allWithSquares = [
    ...numbers,
    if (includeSquares) {for (var n in numbers) n * n}
  ];
  print(allWithSquares); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}]
```

You can read more about new Dart features [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the curly braces from the if. Then you add curly braces in the list it's interpreted as a map

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code if you want the squared value to be inserted after the source value:

```
  List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  var includeSquares = true;
  var allWithSquares = [
    for (var n in numbers)
      if (includeSquares) ...[n, n * n],
  ];
  
  print(allWithSquares); // [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Same result, but without if statement:

```
  List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  var allWithInsertedSquares = [
    for (var n in numbers) ...[n, n * n],
  ];

  print(allWithInsertedSquares); // [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to be like this:

```
if (text.length > 0) ...{
         for (var val in text) Center(child: etc..)
        }
```

for more info you can check this site:
[What’s New In Dart 2.3?](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)